# Parameter expansion in bash for loop to retreive key and value

Tags: bash

I'm not sure what is doing this `for loop` in Bash that is using this kind of parameter expansions `var_key="${env%%=*}"`

```
    for env in "${envvars[@]}"; do
        var_key="${env%%=*}"
        var_value="${env#*=}"
        if [[ -z ${!var_key} ]]; then
            echo "export ${env}" >> "${FILE}"
            echo "export ${var_key}=\"${var_value}\"" >> "${FILE}"
        fi
    done
```

Any idea of what is being doing this `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"${env%%=*}"` is one possible form of a "parameter expansion". It removes the longest match of the pattern `=*` from the value of the variable `$env`.
`#` is similar but operates on the beginning of the value.

E.g.

```
env=x=3=6
echo ${env%%=*}  # x
echo ${env%=*}   # x=3
echo ${env#*=})  # 3=6
echo ${env##*=}) # 6
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any reference link that explains that?

Comment: For example [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), but `man bash`  mentions it, too.

Comment: man bash .... 8-) look for the section on parameter expansion